# Transport/flow network in GAP

Tags: graph-theory, gap, network-flow, network

How to define a transport network in GAP? I can't seem to find a single function related to transport networks or flows in general in the GAP-GRAPE manual. I'd be content with just manually adding weighted edges in directed graphs but the best I found was adding weights to vertices, something I don't think could help me. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Neither GAP, nor GRAPE has specific functionality for transport networks or optimization.

Comment: @ahulpke Is there no way I could add weights on my own then?

Comment: Can't see such functionality in two other packages - [Digraphs](http://gap-packages.github.io/Digraphs) and [YAGS](http://xamanek.izt.uam.mx/yags/) as well. I can't think of any fundamental obstacles not permitting adding weights, but I don't know which of the three would be most suitable for such an extension. Note that YAGS is not redistributed with GAP.